# Compare two audio files with persons speaking and compute the similarity score

Tags: python, audio, librosa

**Big picture:** Trying to identify proxy frauds in video interviews.

I have video clips of interviews. Each person has 2 or more interviews. As a first step I am trying to extract the audio from the interviews and trying to match them and identify if audio is from the same person.

I used python library **librosa** to parse the audio files and generate MFCC and chroma_cqt features of those files. I went ahead to also create a similarity matrix for those files. I want to convert this similarity matrix to a score between 0 to 100 where 100 is perfect match and 0 is totally different. After which I can identify a threshold and provide labels to the audio files.

**Code:**

```
import librosa

hop_length = 1024
y_ref, sr1 = librosa.load(r"audio1.wav")
y_comp, sr2 = librosa.load(r"audio2.wav")
chroma_ref = librosa.feature.chroma_cqt(y=y_ref, sr=sr1, hop_length=hop_length)
chroma_comp = librosa.feature.chroma_cqt(y=y_comp, sr=sr2, hop_length=hop_length)

mfcc1 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y_ref, sr1, n_mfcc=13)
mfcc2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y_comp, sr2, n_mfcc=13)


# Use time-delay embedding to get a cleaner recurrence matrix
x_ref = librosa.feature.stack_memory(chroma_ref, n_steps=10, delay=3)
x_comp = librosa.feature.stack_memory(chroma_comp, n_steps=10, delay=3)

sim = librosa.segment.cross_similarity(x_comp, x_ref, metric='cosine')
```

Comment: i have never used it but 'vosk' has a speaker recognition model. https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api

Comment: What does proxy fraud mean exactly? Is it that a person is trying to pass for someone else?

Comment: @JonNordby some other person is giving voice over in the interview while the actual candidate is just lip sync it.

Comment: Then it sounds like what you should do is to compare the audio with video, ie detect the lip syncing itself? This could be challenging under varying video/audio transmission conditions, but with a suitable dataset is something deep learning should be able to solve (assuming that humans can solve it)

Comment: @JonNordby I started with comparing audio because I thought comparing lip syncing will be very complex and I may need to create model from scratch.

Comment: Yes it is a rather big undertaking. So starting somewhere else may make sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of identifying who is talking is called *Speaker Identification*.
Checking whether two audio clips have the same speaker *Speaker Verification*. If there are multiple speakers in dialog, then it may also be relevant to do *Speaker Diarization*, finding out who-talks-when. That would enable focus on the interview subject and not the interviewer.

Speaker recognition tasks like these are best solved with a deep neural network, as it is quite difficult task to separate the speaker from the words that are spoken. The models generally output a speaker *embedding* - a vector representation that encodes similarity of different person's speech. Then one can apply a simple similarity metric on this representation, such as cosine distance.

There are pretrained models available for this. For example in [pyannote-audio](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio) and in [SpeechBrain](https://speechbrain.github.io/).